# Using git-buildpackage together with git-flow

Tags: git, debian, git-flow, deb

I am using git-flow to manage my projects developments workflow. And I want to integrate the debian packaging in this workflow.
Looking at git-buildpackage, it seems to me that there is some overlap between both, especially for version tagging.

How is it possible to integrate git-buildpackage within the git-flow workflow, particularly in order to generate debian package for each release ?

Answer (score 0):

gbp-buildpackage/gbp-tag can create tags but you don't have to use it. If you want to build a Debian package from each release/tag just make sure gbp-buildpackage builds from that tag:

`git checkout <tag>
gbp buildpackage --git-ignore-branch`

If your Debian package is not a native one but uses upstream tarballs make sure you setup --upstream-tag correctly as well.